# i cant do a python bot, voice chat

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

and i have response like that

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```py
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    vc = await voice_channel.connect()
```